# issue while importing utilities.py

Tags: python-3.x, package

hello everyone i have a problem while importing the utilities package it runs for me an error
here is my code :(i am using google colab )

```
!pip install utilities
```

the error is : ***ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities***

i tried to install this :

```
!pip install data-utilities
```

and it works but when i run this code :

```
from utilities import visualize_classifier
```

it does not work , what should i do please

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`!pip install utilities-package`

https://pypi.org/project/utilities-package/
Or
`from data-utilities import visualize_classifier`

Comment: i have already tried this but it doesn't work , thanks for your answer anyway ^^